# firebase ionic js Get Storage URL

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-storage

i need to get image URL from Firebase Storage. I can typing URL on console but i cant assign as variable.
here is my code:

```
storageRef = storage().ref("/"+this.addr+"/"+this.name);
  storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
    console.log(url);

});
```

So, anyone know how can i get my URL? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: arent you getting the `url` already?

Comment: not rly. i  can typing  url on console, but when i trying assign as varilbe i get error.

Comment: Something like this: storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
        this.currentPhotoAddress = url;
        
    });
?
it generate error.

Comment: error: Runtime Error this is undefined.